# Interchange the order of integral and derivative

Tags: real-analysis

I am just wondering when we can interchange the order of the integral and derivative. And the following is the formal version of my question.

$$\partial_x \int f(x,y)dy = \int \partial_x f(x,y) dy$$

I already know the case if the integral is on a bounded set, then f is $C^1$ can definitely induce the above equation. I am curious if the integral is not just on a bounded interval, and what should be the constraint to have this equation? Like can $\partial_x f(x,y) \in L^1$ induce the equation?

Comment: This holds if there exists a dominating function $g$, i.e. $|\partial_x f(x,y)|\le g(y)\in L^1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most general theorem is in the context of *Lebesgue integration*:

> Let $X \subseteq \mathbf R$ be an open subset, $(\Omega,\mu)$ a measure space and $f:X\times \Omega\longrightarrow\mathbf R$ a map with the following properties:
>
> 1. For each $x\in X$, the function $\;t\longmapsto f(x,t)$ is Lebesgue-integrable,
> 2. The function $x\longmapsto f(x,t)$ is differentiable for almost all $t\in\Omega$,
> 3. There exists a Lebesgue-integrable function $\varphi:\Omega\longrightarrow\mathbf R $ such that for  each $x\in X$ and almost all $t\in \Omega$,
>      $$\smash[t]{\left|\frac{\partial f(x,t)}{\partial t}\right|}\le \varphi(t).$$
>      Then the function $F:x\longmapsto \displaystyle\int_{\Omega} f(x,t)\,\mathrm d\mu(t)$ is differentiable on $X$, and its derivative is
>      $$F'(x)=\int_\Omega\frac{\partial f(x, t)}{\partial x}\,\mathrm d\mu(t).$$

Answer (score 1):

What you're seeking might be a special case of the [Leibniz Integral Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule), which tells you that
$$\frac{d}{dx}\int_{a(x)}^{b(x)}f(x,y)dy=f(x,b(x))b'(x)-f(x,a(x))a'(x)+\int_{a(x)}^{b(x)}\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(x,y)dy.$$
In the case that $a(x),b(x)$ are constant with respect to $x$, then of course $a'(x)=0$, $b'(x)=0$, and we're left with the last term, and we conclude that the integral and derivative signs may be exchanged.