# Interchange derivative and DOUBLE integrations

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, lebesgue-integral, differential-topology

Let $A \times \Theta \subseteq \mathbf{R}^2$ be an open subset, $(\Omega, \mu)$ a measure space and $f: A \times \Theta \times \Omega \rightarrow \mathbf{R}$ a map.

Under which conditions can we state that

$$\frac{d}{d \theta} \int_\Omega \int_A f(x, a, \theta) d\mu(x) da = \int_\Omega \int_A 
 \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} f(x, a, \theta) d\mu(x) da$$

Based on [Interchange the order of integral and derivative](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3131845/interchange-the-order-of-integral-and-derivative), I would expect the conditions that

1. $\theta \rightarrow f(x, a, \theta)$ is differentiable for a.e. $x \in \Omega, a \in A$
2. There exists an integrable function $g$ such that

$$\mid \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}f(x,a, \theta) \mid  < g(x, a)$$

Am I correct? And how can I prove it?

Answer (score 1):

This follows immediately from the result for one integral and Fubini. You just need to take the product measure on $\Omega \times A$.